# Xcode 9, scheme test action "Application Language" not working

Tags: ios, xcode

In a framework, I want to test that some texts are correctly localized. To achieve this with no failures I want to force tests always to be executed in a language, eg German

[image: test action]

However, localized strings are not being localized in German, always in English (development language).

Having an option in test action to achieve this, why is it failing?

Comment: Have you tried that the localization works? Try to change the language and region of the device and then launch the app, it works?

Comment: It works, both using device, simulator and forcing language via scheme.